# how to add day to date in ios sqlite

Tags: ios

I am creating a cricket app. I saved the following data in sqlite:

- matchno
- country1
- flag1
- country2
- flag2
- date
- time
- venue

This data is displayed in a `UITableView`.

My requirement is how to display the list of the next day's matches (example today Eng vs Ban). I want display tomorrow's match (Ind vs Ireland) in my tableview.
I tried to compare today's date and tomorrow's date, and how to write query.

My query is

```
select * from where date = 'Mon Mar 9'
```

It displays the list of today's matches, but I want to display the list of tomorrows matches.
Plz help me.

Comment: I think your date field is string Type?

Comment: No, it is varchar, how to compare today date and tomorrow date

Comment: i am also facing same problem and resolved by storing date in format yyyy-MM-dd . and fire the query `select * from where date > 'yyyy-MM-dd'.`

Comment: in my database date field saved this type Mon Mar 9. how write query

Comment: it is not possible.you have do this by our own code.

Comment: i will change the date field, this type yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Now you can fire query like this `select * from where date > 'yyyy-MM-dd'`

Comment: i was changed my date field, its display next matches, but i want display only tomorrow match. it displays 11th  to 15th march matches. how to write query?

Comment: can you use this one `select * from where date = 'TomorrowDate'`.

Comment: it doesn't display anything.

Comment: please show me, what query you have fire and also the output of query.

Comment: select  * from ICCWorldCupMatchesList WHERE date = '2015-03-11 ' this is my query.

Comment: suppose replace greaterthan(>). it displays next day matches list. how to add current date to day. it display only tomorrow match.

Comment: you have to remove space from date `'2015-03-11 '`

Comment: its working, but how to store tomorrow date in the query

Comment: There are too many approach for this.

Comment: you have convert string to date and add one day on that date that become tomorrowDate and again convert tomorrowDate to string and pass in query.

Comment: any example, how to pass string in query.

Comment: like this select * from ICCWorldCupMatchesList WHERE date = 'tomorrowDate'.

Comment: NSDateFormatter *dateformatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateformatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
        NSString *s_tody=[dateformatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
        NSLog(@"Date : %@",s_tody);

Comment: that one print the today date

Comment: NSDateComponents* deltaComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [deltaComps setDay:1];
        NSDate* tomorrow = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:deltaComps toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];
        NSLog(@"Tomorrow date: %@",tomorrow);                                                                                                This one print the tomorrow date, when will declare tomorrow.

Comment: Thanx for replying. when wil declare TomorrowDate, plz send me example.

Comment: consider my answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//get tomorrow date
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
int daysToAdd = 1;
NSDate *nextDate = [now dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];

NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

//Optionally for time zone conversions
[formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"..."]];

NSString *tomorrowDate = [formatter stringFromDate:nextDate];
```

after this fire query

```
  NSString *query=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"select * from ICCWorldCupMatchesList WHERE date = %@",tomorrowDate];
```

may help you.

Comment: const char *sql ="select  * from ICCWorldCupMatchesList WHERE date = 'tomorrowDate'";  but it shows unused variable tomorrowDate.

Comment: where will declare query object.  i was declared query object in (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,query,-1,&selectstmt,NULL)==SQLITE_OK) but it show error and wrong. error is implicit conversion of an objective-C pointer to 'const char *' is disallowed with ARC. wrong is inccomplatible pointer types passing 'NSString * __strong' to parameter of type 'const char *'

Comment: replace this one  `sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[query UTF8String] ,-1,&selectstmt,NULL)==SQLITE_OK `

Comment: can you achieve your goal?